# Object doesn't support property or method 'bPopup'

Tags: jquery

I am new to Jquery datatable.

My code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">  

<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"   
    src="jquery.bpopup-0.8.0.min.js">
</script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css"/>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.1/css/dataTables.tableTools.css"
    rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var grid;

function RowSelected(rowObject) {
    var selRow = this.GetCellByColumnUniqueName(rowObject, "dmsl");
    //window.alert(selRow.innerHTML);
    //here selRow.innerHTML will hold the value for the selected row contact name
}
function GridCreated() {
    grid = this;
}
function scheduleTraining(id) {
    window.location = '../training/SoldierTraining.aspx?id=' + id;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
        //Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
    $('#dmsl tfoot th').each(function () {
            var title = $(this).attr("title");
            $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;" />');
        });

        // DataTable
        var dmslTable = $('#dmsl').DataTable({
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,  //adds first, last, prev, next, page buttons
            "sAjaxSource": "getdmsl_data.aspx",
            "language": { "emptyTable": "No records to display" },  //handle no records return
            "bProcessing": true,
            "sDom": '<"H"<"floatright"l>r>t<"F"i<"floatright"p>>',   //this removes the global search box from the beginning of the page '<"H"flr>t<"F"ip> would add the search to the header
            "lengthMenu": [[10, 15, 20, 50, -1], [10, 15, 20, 50, "All"]], //add All option to # of records menu
            "oLanguage": { "sInfoFiltered": "" },
            "aaSorting": [[1, 'asc'], [2, 'asc']] ,   //inital sort should be by these columns
            "columnDefs": [{
                "targets": 0,
                "data": null,
                "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                    return '<a ><img src="../images/edit.gif" style="height:18px;width:19px;cursor:pointer;"  alt="Edit"></img></a>';
                }
            }]
        });


        // Apply the search
        dmslTable.columns().every(function () {
            var that = this;

            $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function () {
                if (that.search() !== this.value) {
                    that
                        .search(this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/g, ''))   //only allow letters and numbers in search box
                        .draw();
                }
            });
        });

        $('#dmsl tbody').on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
            var that = this;
            e.preventDefault();
            var rowIndex = $(this).find('td:eq(2)').text();
            //alert(rowIndex);
             //Triggering bPopup when click event is fired
            $('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup();

        });
    });
</script>

<div id="element_to_pop_up">Content of popup</div>

    <div class="codeTabLabel" style="text-align: left;">Warfighter Profiles</div>
    <div class="module" id="pageInfoDiv" style="margin-right: 11px; text-align: left;">
        Use this window to find and update selected Warfighter personal information.
        Read-only data must be updated by EMILPO transaction.
        <br />
        <br />
        To locate a Warfighter, enter search criteria in one or more text boxes
        and click any filter icon
        (<asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/filter.gif" />)
        to display its filter menu.  Select from the filter menu.
        To edit a Warfighter’s personal information click on the corresponding
        Edit (<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/edit.gif" />)
        icon and make your change(s).
        <br /><br />
        To make a training reservation for a Warfighter, click the calendar
        icon (<asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/schedule.gif" />)
        and select the Required Training course.  You will be offered a Class Schedule
        for the selected course.  Click the magnifying glass
        (<asp:Image ID="Image4" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/zoom.gif" />)
        in the Required Training panel to view seat availability by class.
        Click a calendar icon in the Required Training panel to reserve a seat in the
        most appropriate class based on available seats and your unit training cycle.
        A User Notification message displays the result of your action.
        <br /><br />
        To sort data by any column heading, click the heading.
        To reverse the sort order click the heading again.
    </div>
    <br />

<div id="DMSLSelection" style="position: relative; margin-left: 5px; margin-right:10px;height:120px;">
        <fieldset style="border-color: #FFDE28; height:100px;width:100%;">
            <legend class="module"><strong>Unit Selection</strong></legend>
            <table align="center" id="Table2" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" width="100%" border="0">
                <tbody>
                    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                       <Telerik:RadComboBox ID="DMSLSelect" runat="server" Width="400px" Height="150px" AutoPostBack="true" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
                        <Items>
                            <Telerik:RadComboBoxItem  Value="" Text="Select Unit"/>
                </Items>                                                     

                            </Telerik:RadComboBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </fieldset>
    </div>

    <div style="text-align:center;" id="divLegend" runat="server">[<asp:Image ImageAlign="Middle" ImageUrl="~/images/greenline.jpg" ID="Image5" runat="server" />]&nbsp;indicates Warfighter on orders (gain)</div>
    <br />
<fieldset id="wrapperfield" style="border-color: #FFDE28; height:auto;width:100%;" runat="server">
   <div id="wrapper"  runat="server" >
         <div class="floatright"></div>
        <table id="dmsl" class= "hover stripe compact nowrap">  
            <thead>
                <tr>  
                    <th></th>
                    <th>UIC</th>
                    <th>SSN<br />(Last Four)</th>
                    <th>Warfighter</th>
                    <th>Pay Grade</th>
                    <th>MOS</th>

                 </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>UIC</td>
                    <td>SSN</td>
                    <td>Warfighter</td>
                    <td>Pay Grade</td>
                    <td>MOS</td>

                 </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>  
                    <th></th>
                    <th title="UIC"></th>
                    <th title="SSN"></th>
                    <th title="Warfighter"></th>
                    <th title="Pay Grade"></th>
                    <th title="MOS"></th>                       
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
</fieldset>

</asp:Content>
$('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup(); give serror
```

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it. There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: This question is not formatted correctly at all. In addition, Stack Overflow requires a Complete, Minimal, Verifiable Example, which is not the case here.

Comment: Fix code formatting -- a little

Answer (score 1):

The error says that the bPopup library is not loaded properly.

You have mentioned all the required JS libraries from CDN, whereas

> jquery.bpopup-0.8.0.min.js

is alone given without CDN.

1. Verify that you have the particular JS library file in your local server.
2. Else try CDN for Jquery Bpopup too.

   https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bPopup/0.9.0/jquery.bpopup.js